# Wrap XML output as a child element?

Tags: sql-server, xml

For example, I have the following SQL returning an Xml code `<B><A Value="1"/></B>`.

```
select
        1 [@Value]
    for xml path ('A'), root ('B')
```

Now I want to wrap it in `<D><C>......</C></D>` so the expected result will be `<D><C><X><B><A Value="1"/></B></X></C></D>`. I can do it by wrapping the sql as a subquery.

```
select
    (select
            1 [@Value]
        for xml path ('A'), root ('B'), type)
for xml path ('C'), root('D')
```

Is it a way to do it without subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your given case it can be done like this:

```
SELECT  1 [X/B/A/@Value]
FOR XML PATH('C'), ROOT ('D')
```

The result

```
<D>
  <C>
    <X>
      <B>
        <A Value="1" />
      </B>
    </X>
  </C>
</D>
```

But there are (quite often) situations, where you need to wrap this in sub-queries.

Comment: I will have many columns/attributes in the query. So I will need to change the SQL column names for all of them. Maybe I will stick on the subquery approach.